# Why the Image code wont show up in my XML?

Tags: java, android

I am making a register form app and everything works fine until I add the ImageView code inside the XML, then I get an run error when trying to run it. There are no compile errors and the code works fine without the ImageView code, but once that code is added, the program crashes. Please help any suggestion are appreciated. Below as well is the log chat errors I am getting.

```
1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.918 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.921 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hu.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hu.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.922 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hy.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hy.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.924 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nb.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nb.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.927 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.927 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sa.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sa.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 
05-24 20:35:23.928 1284-1284/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)






05-24 20:35:30.674 1609-1625/? E/WebViewFactory: error preparing webview native library
                                                 android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.android.webview
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.fetchPackageInfo(WebViewFactory.java:109)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewApplicationInfo(WebViewFactory.java:116)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewNativeLibraryPaths(WebViewFactory.java:374)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.prepareWebViewInSystemServer(WebViewFactory.java:274)
                                                     at com.android.server.SystemServer$2.run(SystemServer.java:1106)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:11780)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$13.run(ActivityManagerService.java:11691)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                  Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.android.webview
                                                     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:137)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.fetchPackageInfo(WebViewFactory.java:107)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewApplicationInfo(WebViewFactory.java:116) 
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewNativeLibraryPaths(WebViewFactory.java:374) 
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.prepareWebViewInSystemServer(WebViewFactory.java:274) 
                                                     at com.android.server.SystemServer$2.run(SystemServer.java:1106) 
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:11780) 
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$13.run(ActivityManagerService.java:11691) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
05-24 20:35:30.674 1609-1625/? E/WebViewFactory: error starting relro file creator for abi x86
                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Native library paths to the WebView RelRo process must not be null!
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.createRelroFile(WebViewFactory.java:446)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.prepareWebViewInSystemServer(WebViewFactory.java:290)
                                                     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.prepareWebViewInSystemServer(WebViewFactory.java:279)
                                                     at com.android.server.SystemServer$2.run(SystemServer.java:1106)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:11780)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$13.run(ActivityManagerService.java:11691)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
05-24 20:35:30.674 1609-1625/? E/WebViewFactory: relro file creator for x86 crashed. Proceeding without
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.issac_rodriguez.register.MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="NAME"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="42dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="EMAIL"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="PHONE"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etTime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:text="Register!!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="TIME "
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="DAY"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/etTime"
         android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
         android:src="@drawable/donate_" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add your logcat

Comment: How much of it should I add since the log-chat has many lines

Comment: @istackz Add only error part of logcat!

Comment: You're looking for [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) from the crash, which should be a large section of red lines. Please [edit] your question to add it. Please don't put it in comments.

Comment: These errors seem to come from the Android system itself. What kind of device is this? Did you see similar errors on another device?

Comment: Try changing your `drawable` file to `donate_img`, don't put the `_` in last character to see if it works

Comment: Yes i get the same results on another device, like I said before though everything works fine all until the image code is added.